# Setting a string value to none when a class related to it is deleted

Tags: c++, oop, class, vector, iterator

I need help with something which I believe is simple. I can assign a student to a project. But when I delete the project, the student is still keeping the project name. I'm thinking of just renaming it back to "None" but I have no idea on how to do that. Help?

**Edit**
`map<int, Student> mstore` and `vector<int> storeid` added.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
class Human {
public:
    virtual void print() const = 0;
};

class Student : public Human {
protected:
    string studname;
    int studId;
    string project;
public:

    Student();
    Student (string studname, int studId) : studname("Unknown"), studId(0), project("None") 
    {
        cout << "A student is created: Name = " << studname
         << ". Id = " << studId << endl;
    }

    virtual void print() const {
    cout << "Name = " << studname << ". Id = " << studId << ". Project = " << project <<endl; }

    void setSName (string sname) { studname = sname; }
    void setSID (int sID) { studId = sID; }
    void printStudentInfo() const;
    void printStudentInfoline() const;
};

void Student::printStudentInfo() const
{
    cout << "\nStudent name: " << studname << endl;
    cout << "Student ID: " << studId << endl;
    cout << "Project: " << project << endl;
}

void Student::printStudentInfoline() const
{
    cout << studId << ", " << studname << ", " << project << endl;
}

class Project {
protected:
    string projname;

public:
    vector <Student> students;
    vector <int> storeid;

    Project (string projname) : projname(projname) { cout << "Project " << projname << " created" << endl;}

    void setPName (string projname) { this->projname = projname; }

    void add (int& sid) 
    {
        //student.setProject (projname);
        storeid.push_back(sid);
    }

    int returnid(int& a)
    {   
        return storeid[a]; 
    }

    int returnsize()
    {   return storeid.size(); }

    void printproj() const {
        cout << endl << projname << " list: \n";
        cout << "Student(s) : " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < storeid.size(); i++){
            cout << storeid[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    void printprojname() const {
    cout << projname << endl;
    }


};

int main() {
string StudentName;
string ProjectName;

int Studentid;

Student *s1;
Project *p1;

vector<Student> store;
vector<Project> projstore;
map<int, Student> mstore;


map<int, Student>::const_iterator itr;
    for (int n=0; n<3; n++) //loop to create 3 students
   { 
    cout <<"Enter name : ";
    getline(cin, StudentName);
    cout <<"Enter  ID : ";
    cin >> Studentid;

    s1 = new Student(StudentName, Studentid);
    s1->setSName(StudentName);
    s1->setSID(Studentid);
    store.push_back(*s1);
    mstore.insert(make_pair(Studentid, *s1));
    cin.get();
    }
    //print map
    for(itr=mstore.begin(); itr!=mstore.end() ;++itr)
    itr->second.printStudentInfo();

    //itr=mstore.begin()+2;
    //itr.print();




cout << "Enter project name: ";
getline(cin, ProjectName);

p1 = new Project(ProjectName);
p1->setPName(ProjectName);

 //Assigning student to project
    cout << endl;
    cout << "How many students? :" ;

    int y;
    cin >> y;
    for ( int i = 0; i < y; i++){
    cout << "Who would you like to add to this project?" << endl;
    int x = 1;

    for(itr=mstore.begin(); itr!=mstore.end() ;++itr)
    itr->second.printStudentInfoline();

    int insID;
    cout << "Enter ID number: ";
    cin >> insID;
    p1->add(insID);

    /*
    for ( it = store.begin(); it != store.end(); ++it ) {
        // For each friend, print out their info

    cout << x << ". ";
          it->printStudentInfoline();
    x++;

    }
    x = 1;  
    int insS;
    cout << "Enter number: ";
    cin >> insS;
    p1->add(store[(insS-1)]);   //stores selected student into the object
    */

    cout << "\nAdding Student done\n" << endl;
    }
    projstore.push_back(*p1);

    //Mstore finds for related ids and displays them accordingly
cout << "print project"<< endl;
    vector<Project>::iterator pt;
    for ( pt = projstore.begin(); pt != projstore.end(); ++pt ) {
        pt->returnsize();
        for (int i=0; i <pt->returnsize(); i++){
        cout << pt->returnid(i) << endl;

        itr=mstore.find(pt->returnid(i));

        itr->second.printStudentInfo();
        }            
    }


    cout << endl;
    cout << "Deleting project" << endl;
    cout << "What would you like to remove?" << endl;
    int x = 1;

    //storeid will display ids. How do I link them to `store` map?
    for ( pt = projstore.begin(); pt != projstore.end(); ++pt ) {
      cout << x << ". ";
      pt->printprojname();
      x++;
    }


    //Now to delete the selected project
    int delP;
    cout << "Enter number: ";
    cin >> delP;
    cin.ignore();
    system("pause");
    projstore.erase(projstore.begin()+delP-1);

// Students

cout << "\n Current students" << endl;
for(itr=mstore.begin(); itr!=mstore.end() ;++itr)
    itr->second.printStudentInfo();

}
```

Comment: I'd personally give `Student` a vector of `Project` and have the project's name as a property of `Project` itself.

Comment: Sounds good but this is just a portion of my code. I have another class Lecturer that relies on class Project as well.

Comment: Maybe something to link them? class `Class` could have a `Lecturer`, multiple `Student`s, and multiple `Project`s.

Comment: So a totally new class that stores one `Lecturer`, multiple `Students` and Projects? Ah, sounds like a lot of work, since I've come so far with my code already. I just don't know how to refer back to the `store` vector and alter the `string project` of the affected `student` before deleting a `project`

Comment: I think it would provide a clearer link between the classes than trying to relate what are unrelated classes according to your code. I'm not an expert in OOP design, but those are my two cents.

Comment: Is it really important that the project name get set to None automatically?  What if you just have a deleteProject function which deletes the project, but also goes through all the students, finds which ones are referencing the project, and sets them to None?

Comment: @VaughnCato yes I have thought about creating a function that will go through `vector<Student> store` and change the values to None. I just can't come up with the code. Tried using an iterator to `find()`for the project name in `store` but still not working.

Comment: If you want to do it that way, consider using `map<int, Student> store` instead of `vector<Student> store`.

Comment: @reddevil07: Much of your work will entail throwing away code that was sub-optimal.  Get used to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at how you add a Student to a Project:

```
void add (Student& student)
{
  student.setProject (projname);
  students.push_back (student);    // <-- AHA!
}
```

First you assign the Project name to the Student, then the Project stores **a copy of** the Student. After that, the Project has no link to the original Student, and can't inform him/her of its own demise when the time comes.

You'll have to rethink this design; there are three major options: 1) the Students can look up their respective Projects in the store, 2) the Project can look up its Students in the `students` vector, or 3) the Project owns the Students (in which case they should probably be GraduateStudents).

**EDIT:**
If that's the way you want to do it, use `map<int, Student> store` to store the Students, using ID number as an index. Then a Project can have a `vector<int>` (or `set<int>`) of student ID numbers. It can look Students up in the store with ease.

**EDIT:**
To print out the entire collection of students:

```
for(map<int, Student>::const_iterator itr=store.begin(); itr!=store.end() ;++itr)
  itr->second.print();
```

**EDIT:**
If the Project has a `vector<int>` of student ID numbers, then what argument do you think `Project::add(?)` should take?

**EDIT:**
The Project can act on a Student by means of the student ID number and access to `mstore`:

```
// in Project:
mstore[id].whatever()
```

**EDIT:**
Sometimes asking the right question -- or in this case, phrasing the question correctly -- is half the battle. *'Now how do I change "None" to the inserted project name?'* A better way to put it is *'How does the Project change one of its Student's `project` from "None" to `projname`?'* Once you put it that way, the answer is almost obvious:

```
// in Project:
mstore[id].setSProject(projname);
```

Note that `Student` does not yet have `setSProject(string)`, you'll have to add it. Also, note that this solution is not ideal since 1) anybody can change a Student's `project`, and 2) a Student's `project` need not actually be the name of a real Project. There is more than one way to deal with these problems.

Comment: Hmm...  I suggested the students owning projects, but I think projects owning (or might I say pwning) students is much better.

Comment: True, projects owning students sound much better. Where do I start though? Perhaps using composition? `vector <Student*> students` ?

Comment: @reddevil07, what should happen to the Students when the Project ends? If it should return them to the student body (e.g. `students`) then the project must have a pointer or reference to that container. And when you add a Student to a Project, you should not retain a copy of the Student anywhere (e.g. `students`) or there'll be trouble sooner or later.

Comment: @Beta When I add a student to a project it stores the attributes of that student into the `students` vector for that particular object of class `Project`. The student attributes come from the vector `store` which is need to keep record of all created students. When a project is deleted, or in this case erased from vector `projstore` I need the students in `store` to reflect on that. I dont know how to make the change :/

Comment: @Beta Yeah think I'll try the map method of doing it. So in this case, is it still necessary for me to keep the `vector<Student> store` ?

Comment: Okay so I tried using `map<int, Student> store` but how do I print out the whole list of students? I keep getting compile errors when printing out for example `it->second` which is the student object in Student.

Comment: @Beta Thanks! it works right :) Though I'm unsure about how to store a list from the `store` map to the `projstore` vector (Which reminds me, should `projstore` be a map too?)
For example:
`for(map<int, Student>::const_iterator itr=mstore.begin(); itr!=mstore.end() ;++itr)
itr->second.printStudentInfoline();
 
 int insS;
 cout << "Enter number: ";
 cin >> insS; //for instance insS is 2
 p1->add(//what do  add in here?);`

Comment: `Project::add(int&)`. Okay so the user inputs student IDs which is stored into `vector<int> storeid`. I can get that work. Now when it comes to deleting, how do I link the selected `projname` with the associated students?

Comment: How do I return the ID stored in `vector <int> storeid` to int_main()? since it belongs to class `Project` it wont recognize `storeid`

Comment: Okay I got that working now. It's able to print out the student info for the related project. Now how do I change "None" to the inserted project name?